# VBA and Excell: Issue in getting Average of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data in an Excel file whose first column has date & time and other columns have same number of data.

What I want to do is to create a script using VBA which gives the average values for each columns after every 15 minutes and these average value should display on different sheet.

Please refer the image below for an example of the data set.

[image]

As time starts from 12:05 till 13:45, so i need average value for B, C and D columns 12:05 till 12.20, then from 12:25 till 1:40 and so on and please note that time intervals may not be same, so i need a script which consist of loop to read value from column A and average other columns accordingly

See below for what I currently have:

```
Sub AverageTimeCalculation()


    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Sheets("Elysees").Activate
    finalrow = Sheets("Elysees").Range("A12120").Row
    For i = 2 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <= 42286.75 Then
            Sheets("sheet1").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Elysees!cells(i,2))"
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:V2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("B2:V2").Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share with us how yoy try to do this, any VBA code.

Comment: Why 12:05 to 12:20 but 12:45 to 1:40? Is 1:40 a typo? Also -- why do you want to do this in VBA? It is trivially done just using built-in Excel functions.

Comment: Dim finalrow As Integer


 Sheets("Elysees").Activate
finalrow = Sheets("Elysees").Range("A12120").Row

For i = 2 To finalrow

    If Cells(i, 1).Value <= 42286.75 Then

  Sheets("sheet1").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Elysees!cells(i,2))"
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:V2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B2:V2").Select
End If
Next i



End Sub

Comment: Sorry that was typo it should be 12.40 and i need it in VBA as i have total 30000 rows to divide at every 15 minutes and need average of 8 coloumns accordingly, please note that it should average data from 12:05 to 12:20 and give result in other sheet and again consider data from 12:25 till 12:40 and give result and so on.

Comment: @Nav, I have added your code into the Question, so you can delete your comment which contains the code. Will your data set have a reading every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

Paste it into a Module you in your WorkBook with the Sheets "Elysees" and insert a sheet and name it "ElyseesAverage"

```
Option Explicit
Sub AverageTimeCalculation()

    Dim OriginalDataSheet As Worksheet
    Set OriginalDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Elysees")

    Dim AverageDataSheet As Worksheet
    Set AverageDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ElyseesAverage")

    Dim finalrow As Integer
    With OriginalDataSheet
        finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim StartTimeRowReference As Integer
    Dim AverageTimeBlock As Range
    Dim ColumnReference As Integer
    Dim AverageValue As Double ' use double for the decimals
    Dim AverageDataSheetRowReference As Integer

    AverageDataSheetRowReference = 2
    For StartTimeRowReference = 2 To 200 Step 4

        AverageDataSheet.Cells(StartTimeRowReference, "A").Value = OriginalDataSheet.Cells(StartTimeRowReference, "A").Value

        For ColumnReference = 2 To 8

            Set AverageTimeBlock = OriginalDataSheet.Range(Cells(StartTimeRowReference, ColumnReference), _
                                                           Cells(StartTimeRowReference + 3, ColumnReference))

            AverageValue = WorksheetFunction.Average(AverageTimeBlock)

            AverageDataSheet.Cells(AverageDataSheetRowReference, ColumnReference).Value = AverageValue


        Next ColumnReference
    Next StartTimeRowReference


End Sub
```